# Does anyone have a Python 3 Cheat Sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anyone have a python 3 cheat sheet? You know quick reference kind of thing which has everything on one page.

Comment: surely the resources found on google would be far richer than anything you could be suggested here.

Comment: Well i googled a lot and was not able to find a proper cheat sheet. If i would have had it then i would'nt be asking here.

Comment: A proper cheat sheet would be several square meters big.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good one, if you know Python 2 syntax, well:
[Python 2 to Python 3](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/imprint_downloads/informit/promotions/python/python2python3.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/python-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 4):

Not a cheat sheet, but here are two helpful resources for converting to or learning the new features of Python 3 (from my bookmarks):

- [Python 3000 and You (Guido van Rossum)](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/euro2008/Py3kEuro08.pdf) - not really a good tutorial but a good overview
- [Porting your code to Python 3 (Alexandre Vassalotti)](http://peadrop.com/slides/mp5.pdf) - a very thorough look at the most important changes in Python 3